# Do <img> tags in html support animated gifs?

Tags: html, image, gif, animated-gif

I am making a photo upload site, and began to wonder:
Do `<img>` tags in html support animated gifs, and can they actually show animated gifs in their image?

Also, if `<img>` tags **don't** support animated gifs, is there a way to implement that cross browser?

Thanks

Comment: That fact that you know that there are animated gifs makes me ask: Where have you seen them? Think about it.

Comment: I may be oversimplifying, but this question seems like it falls in the "I can't take the 5 seconds to try this out myself" category....

Comment: Both followup comments are wrong. You can open the gif directly in the URL and see it animate, but when it is in an HTML page via an <img> tag you might not see any animation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `img` tag has nothing to do with it - it's the browser rendering engine that needs to support them.

And as far as I know, *all* the mainstream ones support animated gifs, though some give the user control over only showing the animation *once* (why? because they can be incredibly annoying. Think carefully before using them).

Comment: Any idea why the (same) browser might animate the gif when loading the file directly in the  URL, but not animate it in an HTML page in an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 127):

[image: Yes]

Comment: Lol. If you can see the text yes, oscillate in and out of the blue circle, then the browser supports it.

Comment: One of the best things I've seen all day!!

Comment: One of the best things I've seen all day!!

Answer (score 0):

img tag supports JPG/JPEG/PNG/GIF formats.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).